# memcpy() segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, memcpy

i'm serialising a struct to send in via a socket but when I try to deserialise memcpy returns me a segmentation fault

This is my code of serialize (that works):

```
unsigned char serialize(msg_t msg)
{
    unsigned char out_buf[sizeof(msg.id)+sizeof(msg.msg)];
    unsigned char *p = out_buf;

    //Serialize id
    unsigned int idX = htonl(msg.id);
    memcpy(p,&idX,sizeof(idX));
    p += sizeof(idX);

    //Serialize msg
    memcpy(p,msg.msg,sizeof(msg.msg));
    p += sizeof(msg.msg);

    return out_buf;
}
```

and that is Deserialize (That not works)

```
msg_t deserialize(unsigned char buff)
{
    msg_t msg;
    unsigned char *p = buff;
    unsigned int *idX = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
    char *mess = malloc(sizeof(50));

    printf("Deserialization start\n");

    //deserialize id
    memcpy(idX,p,sizeof(unsigned int));
    msg.id = ntohl(idX);
    p += sizeof(idX);
    printf("ID deserializzato\n");

    //deserialize msg
    memcpy(msg.msg,p,sizeof(msg.msg));
    printf("msg deserializzato\n");

    return msg; 
}
```

and this is the struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    char* msg;
} msg_t;
```

I know that i'm making a mistake with idX, but i can't understand what

Comment: The code won't compile as written.

Comment: What is this `50`? Put a space behind each `,` to make your code more readable.

Comment: Use your debugger to see what's going wrong. Is the problem on reading from the source or writing to the destination?

Answer (score 2):

one problem I can see:

```
unsigned char buff
```

should be changed to

```
unsigned char * buff
```

isn't it?
and make sure that buff is sufficiently allocated before passing in

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
memcpy(msg.msg,p,sizeof(msg.msg));
```

the address of `msg.msg` shall be used:

```
memcpy(&msg.msg, p, sizeof(msg.msg));
```

(Deos your code compile without warnings)?

Answer (score 0):

The whole program will likely not do what you plan to do. I have no clue whether msg.msg is a pointer or an array. In first case your sizeof could be wrong.

```
char *mess = malloc(sizeof(50)); // sizeof is designed to return the size of the type, I have no clue whether this will be 4 bytes or 50. My guess is, it will return 4

memcpy(idX,p,sizeof(unsigned int)); // unsigned or not doesn't matter for sizeof

unsigned char *p = buff; // pointer == dereferenced variable ==> not good :(
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
//deserialize msg
    memcpy(msg.msg,p,sizeof(msg.msg));
```

Try doing this

```
msg.msg = malloc(msg.msg, p, sizeof(p));
```